# Cambiar metodo de guardado de imagén en MatLab

Tags: bucle-for, bucles, matlab, guardar

Tengo una duda de como resolver esto. 
Mi código actualmente es funcional, lo único que busco es una forma de cambiar el como se guardan las imágenes.

```
img=imread('pat.jpg');

cont=0;
for a = 1:255 
    for b = 1:255
        for c = 1:255
           img(:,:,1)=a; 
           img(:,:,2)=b; 
           img(:,:,3)=c; 
           cont=cont+1;
           imgsave=sprintf('Filtros/%g.jpg',cont);
           imwrite(img,imgsave,'jpg');
        end
    end
end

imshow(uint8(img));
```

En si cada archivo lo esta guardando como `1.jpg` `2.jpg` `3.jpg`
Pero esta vez quiero que guarde de una manera en **base 20**, osease.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, 10, etc.
```

Lo que trato de hacer es reducir los números que manejan las imágenes ya que cuando una imagen supera el `999,999` pasa automáticamente a notación científica. Llámese el millón `1e+06`(Al menos esto sucede en Windows10). Entonces quiero evitar esto pasándolo a **Base 20** para que el millón lo represente como `65000`.

Comment: Si no deseas la notación científica podrías usar `%d` en lugar de `%g`, la Base 20 creo no es convencional y no existe un carácter de conversión directo, pero podrías convertirlo a base 16 con `%x` o `%X`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno es que la verdad hasta me di vergüenza después de dar con la solución.

Resulta que Matlab tiene su propia función para convertir decimales a Hexadecimal.

```
img=imread('pat.jpg');
num=0;
for a = 0:255 
    for b = 0:255
        for c = 0:255
           img(:,:,1)=a; 
           img(:,:,2)=b; 
           img(:,:,3)=c; 

           num=num+1;

           hex = dec2hex(num,6);

           imgsave=sprintf('Filtros2/%s.jpg',hex);
           imwrite(img,imgsave,'jpg');  
        end
    end
end
```

Lo único que hice fue añadir `hex= dec2hex(num,6)` el cual num es mi variable de iteración de imagen por así decirlo. Entonces esa variable se la paso a "hex" que esta hara la conversión, el "6" representa el formato, ya que una vez se convierta se guardaria como `1.jpg`, entonces el 6 lo que hace es darle el formato de 6 caracteres haciendo que quede así `000001.jpg`(Es meramente estetico).

Total, la variable hex se la paso a `imgsave` en lugar de num y queda listo....
Así que solo añadí una linea para dar con mi respuesta.